# How to give id to an image in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I'm inserting an image in my template file as

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('profile_picture.png', array('alt'=>'frame partner avatar'), array('id'=>'framePartnerAvatar')); ?>
```

Now I'm trying to give style to this image by using the id mentioned, but on checking through Firebug only source and alternate name is visible. Image id is not coming there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the correct syntax:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image(
    'profile_picture.png', 
    array(
        'alt'=>'frame partner avatar',
        'id'=>'framePartnerAvatar'
)); ?>
```

See [`HtmlHelper::image()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::image)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-images) the method used to create images requires two parameters. The first one being the source link and the second one being the options parameter

`$this->Html->image('cake_logo.png', ['alt' => 'CakePHP']);`

Your code should be something along the lines of this

```
$this->Html->image('profile_picture.png', array(
    'alt'=>'frame partner avatar',
    'id'=>'framePartnerAvatar')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$thumb_img = $this->Html->image('yourimage.png',array('alt'=>'yoursite.com','id'=>'yourId'));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. It is currently viewed as a low quality post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that all HTML attributes such as alt, id, class etc needs to be written within a single array, and not multiple arrays.

```
   <?php echo $this->Html->image('profile_picture.png', array(
           'alt'=>'frame partner avatar',
           'id'=>'framePartnerAvatar'
        )
    ); ?>
```

This will certainly generate the following HTML:

```
    <img src="/img/profile_picture.png" alt='frame partner avatar' id='framePartnerAvatar' />
```

Peace! xD